Dates change format alone
My problem is pretty straightforward: I have a UserForm where the user insert two dates, the start_date and the end_date.
When the OK button (btnOK) is pressed, I want the column A populated from the start_date to the end_date.
This is the code:
Sub btnOK_Click()

     Dim myDate as Date
     Dim start_date as Date
     Dim end_date as Date
     Dim k, cont as Long

     start_date = Format(textStart.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")
     end_date = Format(textEnd.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy")

     myDate = Format(start_date, "dd/MM/yyyy")
     k = 0
     cont = 1          ' Every 7 days i want 2 rows-space
     Range("A1").Select

     Do Until myDate = end_date + 1
          Selection.Offset(k, 0).Select
          Selection.Value = Format(myDate, "dd/MM/yyyy")
          myDate = format(myDate + 1, "dd/MM/yyyy")
          k = 0
          If cont = 7 Or cont Mod 7 = 0 Then
               k = k + 3
          Else
               k = k + 1
          End If
          cont = cont + 1
     Loop

End Sub


So, the code works fine, the only problem I have is some dates format. A little example here:
' Italian formatting
start_date = "30/09/2024"
end_date = "10/10/2024"




A
B
C




30/09/2024
Mon
dd/MM/yyyy


10/01/2024
Tue
MM/dd/yyyy


10/02/2024
Wed
MM/dd/yyyy


10/03/2024
Thu
MM/dd/yyyy


10/04/2024
Fri
MM/dd/yyyy


10/05/2024
Sat
MM/dd/yyyy


10/06/2024
Sun
MM/dd/yyyy


empty
empty
empty


empty
empty
empty


07/10/2024
Mon
dd/MM/yyyy


08/10/2024
Tue
dd/MM/yyyy


09/10/2024
Wed
dd/MM/yyyy


10/10/2024
Thu
dd/MM/yyyy



I don't know why, some rows are formatted as MM/dd/yyyy and anything I did helped me.
I can assure you that every cell in column A is formatted as italian date dd/MM/yyyy.
I've seen that I can make it work setting all dates variables as Strings, but I need them as dates for other formulas I use.
Any other suggestion about how make the same thing in a more efficient way would be greatly appreciated!

Remove all the formatting stuff - format is for display only:
Sub btnOK_Click()

     Dim myDate As Date
     Dim start_date As Date
     Dim end_date As Date
     Dim k As Long, cont As Long

     start_date = DateValue(textStart.Value)
     end_date = DateValue(textEnd.Value)

     myDate = start_date
     k = 0
     cont = 1          ' Every 7 days i want 2 rows-space
     Range("A1").Select

     Do Until myDate = end_date + 1
          Selection.Offset(k, 0).Select
          ' Apply desired format to the cell, not the value.
          Selection.Value = myDate
          myDate = myDate + 1
          k = 0
          If cont = 7 Or cont Mod 7 = 0 Then
               k = k + 3
          Else
               k = k + 1
          End If
          cont = cont + 1
     Loop

End Sub

